# SQL Server Autonomous transaction logging

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

Our developer who is familiar with Oracle, has asked for the SQL Server equivalent of autonomous transaction logging. We run SQL Server 2014 and 2017.

After extensive searching, nothing really seems like the obvious choice and almost every post is for SQL Server 2008 and earlier. We would appreciate any type of help.

Comment: From what I can tell, the closest thing in SQL Server would be named savepoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/save-transaction-transact-sql

Answer (score 3):

I am also an Oracle developer. Savepoints are for partial rollback. Oracle autonomous transactions are for partial commits.

Oracle autonomous transactions work like below.

```
Start Transaction1
/*DMLs*/
    Start Transaction2
    /*DMLs*/
    COMMIT only Transaction2 and end Transaction2
ROLLBACK only Transaction1 retaining changes committed by Transaction2 and end Transaction1
```

It seems that SQL server does not allow partial commits. Please check [NestedTransactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx). When an outer transaction is rolled back, the committed inner / nested transactions are also rolled back.